# How to load product_type_data on list.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, product-list, products-view

I’m working on a project where products are added directly from category listing page. No need to go to product page. When i click on “addtocart” button, it goes to the product page and shows message “options required”.

When i check view.phtml file, then i came to know that `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>` is responsible for it. Hence, i want to know

how i can load `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>` on category product listing (list.phtml page).

Answer (score 0):

When you click add to cart it goes to `**public function addAction() of location app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php**` near line no 191 in this function their is a code like `$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();` which consist all parameters passed from the page.

**Things to Note**

When you click on add to cart from listing page it might not getting all required parameter that's why it redirects you to detail page.

1) add product from detail page and add code in `public function addAction(){` near line no 198 like

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($params);
exit;
```

And note all the parameter.

2) add same product from list and note the parameter you will definitely get a difference.

3) if you got a difference in above steps then passed the missing parameters from the listing page.

Hope this will help you. let me know if you required some more details.